# ¿que es una funcion hook en javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, backend, frontend

Tengo una duda sobre que realmente significa este termino y quiero estar seguro de lo que creo que es. Segun lo que puedo entender una funcion del tipo hook simula una clase la cual se puede inicializar con un parametro y te devuelve otras funciones como los metodos de las clases de javascript

por ejemplo

```
    const getContrainsFieldsByStatus = (
  statusSelected: RedemptionStatus | RequestStatus,
  fieldByStatuses: FieldsByStatuses[]
): {
  isRequireField: (field: string) => boolean;
  isDisabledField: (field: string) => boolean;
  requiredFields?: string[];
  editableFields?: string[];
  status?: RedemptionStatus | RequestStatus;
} => {
  const constrainsFields = fieldByStatuses.find((status) => status.status === statusSelected);

  const isRequireField = (field: string): boolean => {
    return ObjectUtils.checkIfExistField(field, constrainsFields?.requiredFields || []);
  };
  const isDisabledField = (field: string): boolean => {
    return !ObjectUtils.checkIfExistField(field, constrainsFields?.editableFields || []);
  };

  return { ...constrainsFields, isRequireField, isDisabledField };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Un hook es una técnica para agregar funcionalidad a un código y/o modificar el comportamiento de este. Un hook proporciona una utilidad similar (sin ser lo mismo) a los callbacks  y eventos.

Por ejemplo, yo creo una función para determinar si un número es par o no.

```
function esPar(valor){
  if(valor%2==0) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Ahora quiero agregarle 2 hook, uno antes que calcule y otro para después.

```
function esPar(valor){
  let respuesta=false;
  if (typeof AntesDeCalular == "function"){
     AntesDeCalular();
  }

  respuesta = valor%2==0; //calculo

  if (typeof DespuesDeCalular == "function"){
     DespuesDeCalular();
  }

  return respuesta ;
}
```

Entonces llamo a las funciones AntesDeCalular y AntesDeCalular siempre y cuando estas existan. Entonces si creamos estas funciones tendríamos algo como esto:

```js
function esPar(valor){
  let respuesta=false;
  if (typeof AntesDeCalular == "function"){
     AntesDeCalular();
  }

  respuesta = valor%2==0; //calculo

  if (typeof DespuesDeCalular == "function"){
     DespuesDeCalular();
  }

  return respuesta ;
}

function AntesDeCalular(){
  console.log("Empiezo a calcular");
}
function DespuesDeCalular(){
  console.log("He terminado de calcular");
}

esPar(3);
```

Ahora una función hook podría tener retornos que modifiquen el comportamiento del código, podría tener un array de funciones para agregar muchas funciones al mismo hook, podría poder pasarle variables, etc.

¿Por qué hacer esto?
Digamos que yo creo una Liberia, para que otros usuarios la ocupen. Entonces puedo agregar estos hook's a mis funciones para brindarles algo de control, información y modificaciones de mis funciones, sin la necesidad que ellos editen mi código. (Además de otras muchas razones válidas)